# How do I make following divs appear under 2 column div layout

Tags: layout, html

Below, I want div A to act as a two column layout for it's inner divs with the other divs below it. However because the image is so tall the following divs end up next to it. How can I make divs B and C appear under the image?

```
<div id='A' style='position:relative'>
    <div id='A1' style='width:50%;float:left;'><img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?maptype=roadmap&sensor=false&size=100x100&markers=color:blue|label:A|51.535908,-0.066271&" /></div>
    <div id='A2' style='width:50%;float:left;'>Chelsea Branch<br/>Branch</div> 
</div>
<div id='B'>
    <b>Description:</b> <br />
    This is a location.
</div><br/>
<div id='C'>
    <b>Address:</b><br />
    123 Fake Stree<br />Chelsea<br />London<br />XH28 5JH<br />United Kingdom<br />
</div>
```

Comment: I would suggest that you put it all inside a `<table>` with no borders instead of `<div>`

Comment: I would, but unfortunately table's don't seem to work on this crazy legacy system I'm using, the table contents disappear. I have no idea why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add "clear" after A1 and A2.

```
<div id='A' style='position:relative'>
    <div id='A1' style='width:50%;float:left;'><img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?maptype=roadmap&sensor=false&size=100x100&markers=color:blue|label:A|51.535908,-0.066271&" /></div>
    <div id='A2' style='width:50%;float:left;'>Chelsea Branch<br/>Branch</div> 
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
<div id='B'>
    <b>Description:</b> <br />
    This is a location.
</div><br/>
<div id='C'>
    <b>Address:</b><br />
    123 Fake Stree<br />Chelsea<br />London<br />XH28 5JH<br />United Kingdom<br />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to make `<div id="A">` contain its descendant elements, even though they’re floated.

This, for some reason, is referred to as a ”clearfix”, and there are a few different ways to do it:

- http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/09/27/clearfix-reloaded-overflowhidden-demystified/
- http://perishablepress.com/new-clearfix-hack/
- http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

There are a few other Stack Overflow questions on the subject too, e.g.

- [What methods of ‘clearfix’ can I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best)

Comment: Thanks for the extra bits of reading material. Hadn't heard of this clearfix stuff.

Comment: You’re very welcome. It’s annoying there isn’t a specific CSS property yet to change this behaviour, but there we are.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
#a2 { clear: right; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MXLSn/

Add `clearfix` class to `<div id='A' style='position:relative' class="clearfix">`

Copy these classes in CSS file

```
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after { content: ""; display: table; }
.clearfix:after { clear: both; }
.clearfix { zoom: 1; }
```

You can use `clearfix` class to any container that has floated elements in it.